# number of differents vector space structures over the same field $\mathbb{F}$ on an abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, abelian-groups

My question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102761/define-two-differents-vector-space-structures-over-a-field-on-an-abelian-group) raised another one. How many differents vector space structures over a field $\mathbb{F}$ we may have on an abelian group?  I know that there are abelian groups that we can not endow it with a structure of vector space over any field, for example $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$. But if an abelian group has a structure of a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, is there an upper bound for ways we can define a different structure? Such as the number of automorphisms of the field $\mathbb{F}$. I am conjecturing according to the answer given before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A $k$-vector space structure on an abelian group $A$ is nothing more than a ring homomorphism $k \to \text{End}(A)$. From this it follows that if $k'$ is another field and $k' \to k$ a field homomorphism, then the composition $k' \to k \to \text{End}(A)$ gives $A$ the structure of a $k'$-vector space. In particular, $k'$ may be any subfield of $k$, and we can also compose with any automorphism of $k'$.

More importantly, since a ring homomorphism $k \to \text{End}(A)$ is necessarily injective, the set of vector space structures on $A$ can be identified (non-canonically) with the set of pairs 
$$(\text{subring of } \text{End}(A) \text{ that is a field } k, \text{automorphism of } k).$$

Comment: I am really sorry! The tittle was wrong. It is the number of differents vector space structures over the same field $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @spohreis: okay, so replace "a field $k$" above with "isomorphic  to $F$." It's still not as simple as counting the automorphisms of $F$ because there may actually be different subrings of $\text{End}(A)$ isomorphic to $F$ (for example there exist fields which embed properly into themselves).